# Consider the function $f(x)=\sin(\cos(x))$. What are the attractive fixpoints for $f(x)$.

Tags: trigonometry, fixed-points

Consider the function $f(x)=\sin(\cos(x))$. What are the attractive fixpoints for $f(x)$, ie. the set of values of $x$ for which $f \circ f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f(x) = x$ in the limit?

Let
$$F_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
F_{n-2}(\sin(\cos(x))&\text{ if }n\geq 2\\
\cos(x)&\text{ if }n=1\\
x&\text{ if }n=0
\end{cases}$$

Does $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} F_{2k}(x)$ exist?

I'm empirically getting a fixpoint close, but not exactly equal to to $\ln(2)$, but I guess that could just be a fluke.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144349/discussion-on-question-by-emanuel-landeholm-consider-the-function-fx-sin-co); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed point(s) are where $f(x)=x$. They are attractive when $|f'(x)|<1$ (equal to 1 is more complex but not relevant here)

But why is the fixed point near $\ln 2$? $\ln 2$ is the solution of $e^x-2=0$.

Instead of the roots of $f(x)-x$, consider the roots of $g(x)=-\cos(x)+\arcsin (x)$. It turns out that the series expansion of $e^x-2$ and $g$ around 0 are the same for the first few terms.

The first disagreement is at the fourth derivative (1 vs -1).

Comment: Thank you!  I tried so many times to reply, but I always got those "8 more to go"... Accepted!